# How to extract force constants for normal modes from ORCA?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, spectroscopy, software

I am following the computational method described in *Scientific Reports*.<sup>[1]</sup> Where the authors analyze the contribution of each excited state normal-modes to the shift of the transition energy. For this calculation they use the force constants of each normal mode.
I am using ORCA but could not understand how to generate the force constants. I did find that the `orca_vib` program generates force constants, but I did not find how to use the output to generate a force constant for the specific normal modes.

I also found this question,<sup>[2]</sup> I am not sure if it solves my problem. I saw the great answer by Jan Jensen who following the equation: $$\tilde{\nu}=\sqrt{k_i^{\prime\prime}}/(2\pi \times 137 \times 5.29\times 10^{-9}).$$ 
Do I just need to plug in my vibrational frequencies and rearrange the equation to get $k$?

#### References:

1. Schweighöfer, F.; Dworak, L.; Braun, M.; Zastrow, M.; Wahl, J.; Burghardt, I.; Rück-Braun, K.; Wachtveitl, J. Vibrational coherence transfer in an electronically decoupled molecular dyad. *Sci. Rep.* **2015,** *5* (1), No. 9368. [DOI: 10.1038/srep09368](https://doi.org/10.1038/srep09368).
2. [How to calculate wavenumbers of normal modes from the eigenvalues of the Cartesian force constant matrix?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74639)

Comment: This question may be well received at the new Materials Modeling SE: https://materials.stackexchange.com/